# Math formulas in MultiCollider

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-button, math-se

Often questions from math.stackexchange.com get into MultiCollider's "hot questions".

Formuli is often main things in such questions, but they doesn't get rendered in the dropdown, instead I see something like this:

[image]

It's tricky to judge whether the question is interesting without viewing the formula.

Can formulas be displayed in MultiCollider?

P.S. I'm surprised that there seems to be no such question already asked on the Meta nor on meta.math.SE.

Comment: Wouldn't fixing this mean adding TeX as a system-wide dependency?  If so, it's way too expensive.

Comment: Can it be done in browser, without adding server-side dependencies? Is there something like "turn on browser-based math rendering for my account" option?